# How to create multiple lags in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I create multiple Lags (Previous Values) in pyspark (Spark Dataframe),

in Python it is like

```
data = pd.DataFrame(time_series_df.Value.copy())
data.columns = ["y"] # the value
for i in range(7, 30): #start from index 7
    data["lag_{}".format(i)] = data.y.shift(i) #create new columns with lag values
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcrxo.png)

how can I do the same with pyspark?

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|               Date|             Value|             lag_1|             lag_2|             lag_3|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2016-12-31 21:00:20|          32.35382|              null|              null|              null|
|2016-12-31 21:00:40|32.366640000000004|          32.35382|              null|              null|
|2016-12-31 21:01:00|32.521359999999994|32.366640000000004|          32.35382|              null|
|2016-12-31 21:01:20|          32.65869|32.521359999999994|32.366640000000004|          32.35382|
|2016-12-31 21:01:40|          32.67517|          32.65869|32.521359999999994|32.366640000000004|
|2016-12-31 21:02:00|          32.68707|          32.67517|          32.65869|32.521359999999994|
|2016-12-31 21:02:20|32.709959999999995|          32.68707|          32.67517|          32.65869|
|2016-12-31 21:02:40|          32.73193|32.709959999999995|          32.68707|          32.67517|
|2016-12-31 21:03:00|32.752990000000004|          32.73193|32.709959999999995|          32.68707|
|2016-12-31 21:03:20|32.752990000000004|32.752990000000004|          32.73193|32.709959999999995|
|2016-12-31 21:03:40|          32.64954|32.752990000000004|32.752990000000004|          32.73193|
|2016-12-31 21:04:00|          32.59644|          32.64954|32.752990000000004|32.752990000000004|
|2016-12-31 21:04:20|          32.52228|          32.59644|          32.64954|32.752990000000004|
|2016-12-31 21:04:40|          32.37762|          32.52228|          32.59644|          32.64954|
|2016-12-31 21:05:00|          32.28699|          32.37762|          32.52228|          32.59644|
|2016-12-31 21:05:20|          32.26044|          32.28699|          32.37762|          32.52228|
|2016-12-31 21:05:40|          32.22565|          32.26044|          32.28699|          32.37762|
|2016-12-31 21:06:00|          32.19818|          32.22565|          32.26044|          32.28699|
|2016-12-31 21:06:20|          32.19727|          32.19818|          32.22565|          32.26044|
|2016-12-31 21:06:40|          32.19727|          32.19727|          32.19818|          32.22565|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

How can I continue until lag 30?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window functions [`lag`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.lag):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().orderBy('y')

for i in range(7, 30): 
    df = df.withColumn(f"lag_{i}", F.lag(F.col('u'), i).over(w))
```

Comment: This worked well, Thank You. Is there another way to so it rather than using loop?

Comment: I dont think so since you are using different value of lags, what you are looking for is a `range` parameter implemented in lag` function but it isn't there yet. if my answer helped, kindly accept and upvote it.

Comment: you can actually use `foldLeft` to accomplish this, because the `withColumn` function returns a DF. Here is my code in Scala: 

 `val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(partitionCols).orderBy(orderCol)
(1 to numLeads).foldLeft(df)((acc, i) => acc.withColumn("lag_%d".format(i), lag('colName', i).over(windowSpec)))`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @YOLO's answer, here is a solution with a internal loop allowing to better chain different expressions. Also it gives a single column as an array, which is more easy to use in an UDF for instance.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().orderBy('y')

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('lags', F.array(*[F.lag(F.col('u'), i).over(w)
        for lag in range(7, 30)])
    )
)
```